# For SEO, is role="heading" aria-level="1" the same as H1?

Tags: seo, heading, technical-seo

On our website, for all instances where I would normally put h1s, it is implemented as a div with a `role="heading" aria-level="1"`

Is this the same as a h1 in terms of SEO?

The website was created by a third party hence my question asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The **[first rule for using ARIA says](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#rule1)**:

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML] or attribute with the
> semantics and behavior you require already built-in, instead of
> re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state, or property to
> make it accessible, then do so.

The **[Html standard says about the `div` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)**:

> The div element has no special meaning at all.

In turn, the h1 element is the most important of **[HTML Section Heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)**. The **[Html standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)** says about this element:

> The h1 element is said to have the highest rank...

From all that has been said, it follows that element `h1` has much more semantic meaning than the aria brought into `div` element. Accordingly, for SEO, the value of the `h1` element is higher than the value of the aria embedded in the `div`.